# JaCoCo maven plugin not covering test for spring boot appplication

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, cobertura, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have below method in my springboot application class, which fetch data from DB

```
public void load(){ 
  Optional<List<Employee>> employee = employeeRepository.findEmployee();
  // Some other code with employee data
}
```

I am writing some Junit 4 Test case for this method and also counting coverage with Jacoco plugin.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeTest{

  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = Mockito.spy(EmployeeRepository.class);

  @Test
  public void shouldLoadDataFromDB(){
    EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService(employeeRepository);
    when(employeeRepository.findEmployee()).thenReturn(buildDataFromDB());
    employeeService.load();
    // Assertions
  }
}
```

For above I am always getting code coverage 0 even though I have covered test for given method,also shows method is not not covered in test.

Can someone give some idea what am I missing here.

**Edit**

I have check in `jacoco-session.html` file, I don't see my classes there. How can I check what I am missing.

JaCoCo documentation saying class Id mismatch will also cause this issue but I don't understand how to check this.
Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Which ide you are using? Did you install plugin & configured the project?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I have configured plugin and in IDE also it is showing no coverage or method not covered in test.

I am running through terminal also but same result

Comment: after running the tests, do you find any jacoco related file like target/site/jacoco/index.html, which runs in browser & shows the test coverage

Comment: Yes, I see target/site/jacoco/index.html file and I can see in that file (when I run it on chrome) also coverage is zero or zero lines covered.

Comment: Is i get access to your project, i will run & check, if it is not confidential

Comment: Hi Dinesh, thank you for your response, but I can not give the access to the project, but it really helps if you can give me any pointer or area where I can look into.